# Why do we have to copy all files into dedicated folder when doing unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, manual-testing

I'm using Mocha Library and the Library by default use a Test folder. So, I have to copy the code I written in production into Test folder when doing Unit Tests with Mocha.

Anyone can think reason behind this method? Is it appropriate?

I'm just a hobbyist, haven't done programming for large companies. I also avoided unit tests thru Mocha for years but it seems it's right time for me to actually start to use Mocha to remove manual testing pain.

EDIT: Actually, I can import the code directly from Production but the practice among examples I witnessed is to use dedicated folder for Unit Tests, I looking to understand reasons behind this practice.

Comment: Automate the copy.

Comment: @Robert Harvey What's the tool you are using for that?

Comment: It could be as simple as a batch file or build script.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I'm just curious, Why do I still have to do this when I can directly link the production code into this library? Any reasons behind that?

Comment: I think you might have some misconceptions about Mocha.  I did a bit of reading [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-quick-and-complete-guide-to-mocha-testing-d0e0ea09f09d/), which suggests that your *tests* go into the "Test" folder, not your code under test.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This article and few more articles even example Github repos shows that the code should go inside test folder. For example, "Create a new sum.js file in the test directory of your project and add the following code snippet to it"

Comment: That just sounds like an example to get you started.  I would suggest following that article I linked; see if you can refer to your production files directly, in their original folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normal to keep tests in a separate directory because they are not part of the code that would be deployed. But it's also standard practice to *import* the code you want to test into the test code, without *copying* any code around.

For illustration, I opened up a [random test](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/54475eb4ca35a2c9044a1b8c59a60f09c73e6c01/test/unit/throw.spec.js#L5) from Mocha.JS' own test suite, and it does this:

```js
var Mocha = require('../../lib/mocha');
```

Comment: I do understand the test cases must be in Test Folder but the examples I followed had copied even the code into test folder. That was my initial confusion and thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @sqlbie I have never seen a test suite that copies the code under test into the test suite. But I don't do much JavaScript, so it could be a common practice for some folks? Might be necessary when Babel isn't properly configured? There are also many third party resources and blog posts that, umm, aren't very good, especially in the web development community – evaluate sources critically.